# For Loop and If in R Programming

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, plot, histogram

I think I have a simple question, but I can not figure out how to do it.
I just wanna plot all hist of an data input and check if all var are numerical.

```
plotting_histogram_data<-function(x) {
  for(i in seq_len((ncol(x)))) {
    if(is.numeric(x[,i])) { 
      hist(x[,i])
    }
    else{
      print("Variable is not of the Typ numeric!")
    }
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is the index.

Thank and have nice day.

Comment: What's the problem here? This seems to generate all the different histograms as requested. You only seem to be using one graphics device so when each one plots, it will overwrite the other. Rstudio keeps a history of the plots that you can browse through. The you want to plot them all on one image? How did you want to arrange them?

Comment: what MrFlick says is correct. If you use it on Rstudio on mtcars dataframe it will output all histograms. try looping on names(x) in order to get variable name in the plot. `plotting_histogram_data<-function(x) {
  for(i in names(x)) {
    if(is.numeric(x[, i])) { 
      hist(x[, i], main = i)
    }
    else{
      print(paste(i, "Variable is not of the Typ numeric!"))
    }
  }
}`